# What is the text in which the Buddha gets a migraine?

Tags: karma, the-buddha, reference-request

In the [Great Minds of the Eastern Intellectual Tradition](http://www.thegreatcourses.co.uk/courses/great-minds-of-the-eastern-intellectual-tradition.html) lecture series Grant Hardy mentions that there is a Buddhist sutra or text when the Buddha gets a migraine (it's probably not described as a migraine I should imagine). It's apparently an example of the fruits Buddha's previous karma arising even after he was enlightened. Does anyone know the text that this happens in?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I'd heard about it too (in a Dan Ingram Buddhist Geeks podcast, I think) but could never find it. BTW, could you give a rough location to where it's mentioned in Hardy's lecture series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in [Why the Buddha Suffered](http://ancient-buddhist-texts.net/English-Texts/Why-the-Buddha-Suffered/index.htm) ([The Connection with Previous Deeds](http://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Connection-with-Previous-Deeds/) / [Apadāna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apad%C4%81na) 39.10).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It is the one. Particularly as there are a lot of other ailments which Grant Hardy alluded to. Thanks

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala, the first two of those links seem to be broken. Can you check them?

Comment: The site is down but this is in the Apadana. Matter of finding another translation.